# How to split abbreviated days of the week?

Tags: php, string, validation, split, days

I'm trying to split the string `MTWTHFS` (days of the week) and store it as an array.

I've tried `str_split()` but it will also split `T` and `H` for Thursday.

```
if(strpos($days, 'TH') !== false) {
    $withth = str_replace("TH", "" ,$days);
}else{
    $day = str_split($days);
    print_r($day);  
}
```

I also tried first removing the `TH` in the string before splitting it.
`str_split()` is fine when there is no `TH` in the string.

This is my desired result:

```
array([0]=>'M', [1]=>'T', [2]=>'W', [3]=>'TH', [4]=>'F', [5]=>'S')
```

Are there any better ways to do this?

Comment: @mickmackusa i have an input where in user will enter class schedule. e.g 7:30 am-9:00 am MTWTH Room1. so i have to split the days which is MTWTH and store them individually. so i should come up with array([0]=>'M', [1]=>'T', [2]=>'W', [3]=>'TH'). im looking this as an end result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there will be a few ways to do this.  Here is one way with `preg_split()`

Code: ([PHP Demo](https://3v4l.org/GGP81))

```
$days = 'MTWTHFS';
$split = preg_split('/.H?\K/', $days, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_export($split);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'M',
  1 => 'T',
  2 => 'W',
  3 => 'TH',
  4 => 'F',
  5 => 'S',
)
```

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bGY3At/1)

---

For anyone who wishes to use a non-regex method for any reason, this will do the same:

```
$days = 'MTWTHFS';
for ($i = 0, $k = -1, $len = strlen($days); $i < $len; ++$i) {
    if ($days[$i] == 'H') {
        $split[$k] .= 'H';
    } else {
        $split[++$k] = $days[$i];
    }
}
```

---

It seems PHP 5.5 doesn't like `\K` in the pattern.  This will provide the desired result:

```
$split = preg_split('/(.H?)/', $days, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: this one did the trick if the days string has TH on it. how about when no TH in the string? Like MTFS? or MWF

Comment: im getting an incorrect output array ( 0 => 'M', 1 => 'TW', 2 => 'TH', 3 => 'FS', )

Comment: @Raymond Either of my methods will work regardless of the occurrence of `H`.  Feel free to use the PHP Demo link that I provided in my answer.

Comment: i tried the demo you gave and it works properly in version 7. but i tried running it lower to 5.5 which im currently using and the result is not the same. i might try the other one you provided. thanks

Comment: @Raymond I added a third solution for your version.

Comment: the third one did the trick @mickmackusa, works like a charm. thank you so much